# Kill Process in task manager using WPF with hosted Winform

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a WPF app which hosts a Winform form inside a usercontrol. When I close the application the whole wpf app is still live in the Processes of Windows task manager. There are probably ways for me to fix this by reviewing the whole code but I have limited time available. I was wondering if on the close of the WPF app I could kill the process of the whole app in task manager. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to kill processes by adding

```
      protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        Environment.Exit(0);

    }
```

In the MainWindow.cs code behind